# Make my Word template appear on every new page

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Now I use code to fill one document:

```
Sub UpdateDocuments()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
        .Bookmarks.Item("Company_Name").Range.InsertAfter Prefix & " " & Company_Name
        .Bookmarks.Item("Company_Street").Range.InsertAfter Company_Street
        .Bookmarks.Item("Company_Street_Nr").Range.InsertAfter Company_Street_Nr
        .Bookmarks.Item("Company_PostCode").Range.InsertAfter Company_PostCode
        .Bookmarks.Item("Company_City").Range.InsertAfter Company_City
        .Bookmarks.Item("Company_Country").Range.InsertAfter Company_Country
        ' here need to do the same thing from 1 to 100 times again, but with other data
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But how to reuse this template again in the same open instance, so after filling first Bookmarks, create new same template in the same document as next page and fill them again?

So i need something like

```
Sub UpdateDocuments()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
        fillbookmarks ' with new data
        add new page from the same strFile
        fillbookmarks ' with new data
        add new page from the same strFile
        fillbookmarks ' with new data
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: code running from excel vba

Comment: Take a look at Word's `InsertFile` method: Is this what you mean? That's one possibility. Another would be to save the text that repeats as a Building Block in a real template file (dotx or dotm - use Documents.Add to create your new document instead of opening an existing one, then no one has to worry about using SaveAs to avoid over-writing the original) and insert that as required.